# How to change ContentControl's Content property using DataTemplate's DataTriggers based on Window's ViewModel property which is an enum value

Tags: wpf, enums, view, datatemplate, datatrigger

I ask for your help in solving something that is simply said and most likely simply done but not for me at the moment.
What I'm developing is an application that looks like Office 2013 using FluidUI control set.
I want to achieve view switcher from Word/Access where on ribbon there is Views tab and there are buttons which switches views.
I thought that storing whole View object inside my ViewModel's property CurrentView is wrong way and I try to make this application as MVVM pure as possible. This application is more like "How to write app using MVVM" because I'm still learing WPF.
Ok. So I have my Window (MainWindowModern to be correct) which has Fluid Ribbon. There are 3 buttons to switch views (I call them Editors).
What they do is to change MainWindowModern's ViewModel's CurrentView property and set new enum value to it. This part of setting new enum value is done and works.
Now. The main body of the window is just ContentControl. Now I want to change this ContentControl's Content property based on DataContext.CurrentView property value. Like I said it before. I don't want to do any code-behind inside view's c# (i'm writing this app in C#) file.
The only thing that doesn't work is just changing ContentControl Content property. I'm trying to do this using DataTemplates and DataTemplate.Triggers

Now here's what I've got so far (without unrelated code).

The Window's XAML

```
<Fluent:MetroWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Fluent="clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent"
    xmlns:localVM="clr-namespace:MVVMTest.ViewModels"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMTest"
    x:Class="MVVMTest.Views.MainWindowModern"
    x:Name="ThisWindow"
    Title="Dialogue Editor (Modern UI Version)"
    Width="1280" Height="480"
    RibbonThemeColor="Red" WindowState="Maximized"
    Icon="..\Assets\App\AppIcon_32x32.png">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CharactersEditorTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="Characters Editor Template Body" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ChaptersEditorTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="Chapters Editor Template Body" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ConversationsEditorTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="Conversations Editor Template Body" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="aaa" DataType="{x:Type ContentControl}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=DataContext.CurrentView}" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView}">
                    <DataTrigger.Value>
                        <localVM:EditorView>CharactersEditor</localVM:EditorView>
                    </DataTrigger.Value>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource CharactersEditorTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView}">
                    <DataTrigger.Value>
                        <localVM:EditorView>ChaptersEditor</localVM:EditorView>
                    </DataTrigger.Value>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ChaptersEditorTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView}">
                    <DataTrigger.Value>
                        <localVM:EditorView>ConversationsEditor</localVM:EditorView>
                    </DataTrigger.Value>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ConversationsEditorTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>-->

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=DataContext.CurrentView}">
                    <DataTrigger.Value>
                        <localVM:EditorView>ChaptersEditor</localVM:EditorView>
                    </DataTrigger.Value>
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ChaptersEditorTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <localVM:MainWindowVM />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" LastChildFill="True">
        <Fluent:Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top">

            <Fluent:RibbonTabItem Header="VIEW" Fluent:KeyTip.Keys="V" ReduceOrder="ViewsRibbonGroupBox, ViewsRibbonGroupBox, ViewsRibbonGroupBox">

                <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Name="ViewsRibbonGroupBox" Header="Views">

                    <Fluent:Button Name="CharactersViewButton" 
                                   Header="Characters" 
                                   LargeIcon="..\Assets\Ribbon\View\CharacterEditorIcon_32x32.png"
                                   Icon="..\Assets\Ribbon\View\CharacterEditorIcon_32x32.png"
                                   Command="{Binding SwitchToCharactersEditorCommand}" >
                        <Fluent:Button.ToolTip>
                            <Fluent:ScreenTip
                                Image="..\Assets\Ribbon\View\CharacterEditorIcon_32x32.png"
                                Title="Characters Editor"
                                Text="Changes current view to Characters Editor view.&#x0a;&#x0a;In this view user can:&#x0a;&#x2022; List existing characters&#x0a;&#x2022; Create new characters&#x0a;&#x2022; Edit existing characters&#x0a;&#x2022; Delete existing characters&#x0a;&#x0a;It is also possible to manage character's emotions in this view." />
                        </Fluent:Button.ToolTip>
                    </Fluent:Button>

                    <Fluent:Button Name="ChaptersViewButton" 
                                   Header="Chapters" 
                                   LargeIcon="..\Assets\Ribbon\View\ChapterEditorIcon_32x32.png"
                                   Icon="..\Assets\Ribbon\View\ChapterEditorIcon_32x32.png"
                                   Command="{Binding SwitchToChaptersEditorCommand}" >
                        <Fluent:Button.ToolTip>
                            <Fluent:ScreenTip
                                Image="..\Assets\Ribbon\View\ChapterEditorIcon_32x32.png"
                                Title="Chapters Editor"
                                Text="Changes current view to Chapters Editor view.&#x0a;&#x0a;In this view user can:&#x0a;&#x2022; List existing chapters&#x0a;&#x2022; Create new chapters&#x0a;&#x2022; Edit existing chapters&#x0a;&#x2022; Delete existing chapters&#x0a;&#x0a;It is also possible to manage chapters's missions in this view." />
                        </Fluent:Button.ToolTip>
                    </Fluent:Button>

                    <Fluent:Button Name="ConversationsViewButton" 
                                   Header="Conversations" 
                                   LargeIcon="..\Assets\Ribbon\View\ConversationEditorIcon_32x32.png"
                                   Icon="..\Assets\Ribbon\View\ConversationEditorIcon_32x32.png"
                                   Command="{Binding SwitchToConversationsEditorCommand}" >
                        <Fluent:Button.ToolTip>
                            <Fluent:ScreenTip
                                Image="..\Assets\Ribbon\View\ConversationEditorIcon_32x32.png"
                                Title="Conversations Editor"
                                Text="Changes current view to Conversations Editor view.&#x0a;&#x0a;In this view user can:&#x0a;&#x2022; List existing conversations&#x0a;&#x2022; Create new conversations&#x0a;&#x2022; Edit existing conversations&#x0a;&#x2022; Delete existing conversations&#x0a;&#x0a;It is also possible to manage conversations's statements and statement's stages in this view."
                                DisableReason="Please define at least one chapter with at least one mission in it to enable Conversations Editor.&#x0a;Also it would be helpful to define at least one character with at least one emotion.&#x0a;It is optional action but highly recommended." />
                        </Fluent:Button.ToolTip>
                    </Fluent:Button>

                </Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
            </Fluent:RibbonTabItem>

        </Fluent:Ribbon>

        <ContentControl Name="MainContent" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource aaa}" />

    </DockPanel>
</Fluent:MetroWindow>
```

Window's ViewModel and the enum

```
using MVVMTest.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVVMTest.ViewModels {
    public enum EditorView {
        CharactersEditor,
        ChaptersEditor,
        ConversationsEditor
    }

    public class MainWindowVM : ViewModelBase {

        public MainWindowVM() {
            this.init();
        }

        protected void init() {
            this.Characters = new ObservableCollection<CharacterVM>();

            this.initCommands();
            this.initSampleData();
        }

        protected void initSampleData() {
            Character ch1 = new Character() { Name = "Character 1" };
            Emotion e1 = new Emotion() { Name = "Emotion 1" };
            ch1.Emotions.Add(e1);
            CharacterVM ch1vm = new CharacterVM(ch1);
            this.Characters.Add(ch1vm);

            this.CurrentView = EditorView.ConversationsEditor;
        }

        protected void initCommands() {
            this.SwitchToCharactersEditorCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.SwitchToCharactersEditor(), param => this.CanSwitchToCharactersEditor());
            this.SwitchToChaptersEditorCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.SwitchToChaptersEditor(), param => this.CanSwitchToChaptersEditor());
            this.SwitchToConversationsEditorCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.SwitchToConversationsEditor(), param => this.CanSwitchToConversationsEditor());
        }

        public ObservableCollection<CharacterVM> Characters { get; set; }

        protected EditorView _currentView;
        public EditorView CurrentView {
            get { return this._currentView; }
            set {
                if (this._currentView == value) {
                    return;
                }
                this._currentView = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
            }
        }

        #region Commands

        #region View Tab

        #region Switch To Characters Editor
        public RelayCommand SwitchToCharactersEditorCommand { get; private set; }
        protected void SwitchToCharactersEditor() {
            this.CurrentView = EditorView.CharactersEditor;
        }
        protected bool CanSwitchToCharactersEditor() {
            if (this.CurrentView != EditorView.CharactersEditor) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        #endregion Switch To Characters Editor

        #region Switch To Chapters Editor
        public RelayCommand SwitchToChaptersEditorCommand { get; private set; }
        protected void SwitchToChaptersEditor() {
            this.CurrentView = EditorView.ChaptersEditor;
        }
        protected bool CanSwitchToChaptersEditor() {
            if (this.CurrentView != EditorView.ChaptersEditor) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        #endregion Switch To Chapters Editor

        #region Switch To Conversations Editor
        public RelayCommand SwitchToConversationsEditorCommand { get; private set; }
        protected void SwitchToConversationsEditor() {
            this.CurrentView = EditorView.ConversationsEditor;
        }
        protected bool CanSwitchToConversationsEditor() {
            if (this.CurrentView != EditorView.ConversationsEditor) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        #endregion Switch To Conversations Editor

        #endregion View Tab

        #endregion Commands
    }
}
```

When this is all done the next step is to add animation to view switch just like on ModernUI Apps (or android smartphones) so the old content goes over the border of the window and new content comes from the other side. If it is not possible then I'll stop with just working switcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is that this is actually pretty easy to do, including the animation switching. What you need is an ItemsControl to host your subviews. The ItemsControl allows you to use a DataTemplateSelector. So based on your enum value you can produce some output that the selector can use to determine which datatemplate to use. Try some research on the selector. If your are still confused feel free to reach out to me.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.

Comment: 1. Why should I use ItemsControl? ContentControl also has DataTemplateSelector. Can't it be used instead of ItemsControl?
2. Why use DataTemplateSelector when what I think really needs to be done is to trigger DataTemplate to change contents of ContentControl based on enum value which I can access? I'm not saying that what you've suggested is bad/wrong but maybe why my approach is bad?

Also I am confused about the selector as you said.

Comment: Ok. Somehow I've managed to create this selector and now it works. But I've used it with ContentControl rather than ItemsControl. And second but: I've used this tutorial: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: Now you said something about animations. Could you provide me with some source on how to accomplish this?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response.  ContentControl is perfectly viable.  ItemsControl is typically used for multiple pieces of content, whereas a ContentControl is used for a single piece of content.  Since I deal in multiples all day, that's my usual go-to control.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: That's no problem. I somehow checked the difference between  those two controls and what I found out is that ContentControl expands to fill whole space of the container it is placed in contrast to ItemsControl which set's it's size to maximum element in the list so other elements can also be viewed but it also have ContentTemplateSelector as ContentControl. The only thing I don't understand is why my previous approach was bad. The only thing that wasn't working there was triggering correct DataTemplate Trigger to change Content property of ContentControl.

Comment: Ok. So as you previously said that it wouldn't be hard to create the effect I wanted using Selectors and even the animation. So since now my views changes then how to achieve the animation effect?

Answer (score 0):

For animations, I suggest a container control that would host your subviews.  Check out [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/197132/Simple-WPF-Page-Transitions) for a pretty solid implementation to get you started.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I didn't see you posted second reply.